# MacTeX user with TeX Live Utility Issues

Tags: texlive

I have TeX Live Utility 2013 on my Mac and recently have been having issues with it. When I open it I get the following message:

"Your TeX Live version is 2013, but your default repository URL appears to be for TeX Live 2014.  You need to manually upgrade to a newer version of TeX Live, as there will be no further updates for your version."

So, I selected upgrade and it took me to the MacTeX website where I downloaded (or think I did) TeX Live Utility for 2014. However, when I open this it still gives me the same message. Furthermore, inside TeX Live Utility I selected check for updates and it informs me that I have the most recent version, TeX Live Utility 1.19.

Finally, I did attempt to change the repository a few times but I get the same message.

How do I update to TeX Live Utility 2014 appropriately?

I appreciate the help very much! I am relatively new to TeX and I am sure this is a simple fix but I have yet to find it, so many thanks.

Comment: I think you should update your TeX installation. Install MacTeX-2014 from https://tug.org/mactex/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

As @Papiro said, you need to download [MacTeX.pkg](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/MacTeX.pkg) and install it. The alert sheet in TeX Live Utility is telling you to manually upgrade, or at least that's the intent:

[image]

I guess the button is the misleading part, so maybe that should be changed. TeX Live Utility itself has nothing to do with the upgrade process, where by "upgrade" I mean going from e.g., 2013–2014. TeX Live Utility does let you apply "updates" for the latest version of TeX Live.